# Unable to access administrator page - joomla 3.5.1

Tags: administrator

So, I've done a fresh install of Joomla 3.5.1 and when I go to /administrator, it simply will not let me log in. I'm more than certain I'm entering correct information, I've checked to ensure plg_user_joomla and plg_authentication_joomla are enabled.

What else could this be?

PS! I'm quite new to the platform.

Thank you!

Aron

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to login? Have you checked your server logs? In the `configuration.php`, set `$error_report` to `'development'` and try again

Comment: According to the logs, my user does not exist. However, it is clearly there in jos_users and in jos_user_usergroup_map group_id 8 shows my user_id.

Edit: Regular log in on the front end works nicely.

Comment: It's possible that the user does not belong to the correct user group (you don't have the permission to login to the backend). Check the `jos_user_usergroup_map` table and your user should have a `group_id` of `8`

Comment: My user_id is 742 and the only line in jos_user_usergroup_map is user_id 742 + group_id 8

Comment: How odd. Is this on a live server on localhost? What actually happens when you try to login? Does is say that your username and/or password do not match?

Comment: It's on a live server. When I enter the credentials, the prompt just blinks for a moment and then it's back.

Comment: Ok, I think it may be best you contact your hosting provider to see if there are any server settings they have enabled that could be preventing you from logging in. Joomla itself, AFAIK  doesn't have any issues like this. Before contacting them, try deleting the Joomla installation and installing it again from scratch. Do not use the hosting's 1-click install. Download it from the official website and manually create your database name and username

Comment: Aha! Me big dumdum. I had not figured the host would add an extra log in for added security. 
Got it now. :)

Comment: Ahh good good. Please could you write the solution as a proper answer below and mark it as accepted when allowed to do so?

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you for taking the time! Would probably been stuck for a few more days without a second opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Hosting service had added an extra log in BEFORE the actual Joomla admin login.
Checked with host for said credentials.